# Windows in crashing with Blue screen of death

Tags: windows, windows-10, operating-system, bsod

This is a recent problem I am facing with windows 10 in laptop. I first noticed that while installing a game 'League of Legends' client in Garena platform. The installation struck and it first showed the blue screen. I don't remember the stop code. Then I tried to manually install the game. While installing it struck and again blue screen came.

Then I tried to paste the client file to another folder and while pasting it gave blue screen. The file size is 11 GB. It also struck while unzipping.

After that period, it installed with Garena s/w once. Then after 2 days it gave update and while installing it gave the same problem.
I then uninstalled the game and garena s/w.

Then I tried to install 'Dota 2' with Stream. And there also the blue screen problem occurred. The Problem occurred while executing this command also `dskchk D: /f /r`.

Noticeable here is that,

1. I installed some small s/w after the problem started but that didn't
   give any problem.
2. I noticed that in the task manager the disk usage always gets 100% and stays there. Then in some point the PC gets struck. I sometimes noticed that the processes shows 0% but overall shows 100% disk uses. While getting struck there are some noise from the hard disk.
3. I am installing them in D: drive.
4. The recent hardware I added is Headset and mouse.

### Some of the 'stop code's it showed are:

> 1. memory management

> 2. unexpected store exception

> 3. kernel data inpage error

> 4. critical process died.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem seems to be solved. The things I did that worked is:

1. I observed **Event Viewer** in my PC. I identified the errors that occurred during the crush and researched them.
2. At last the one that worked is: It seemed the memory management of the PC(dump file creation) was not happening. So, I thought why it is happening and came to a conclusion that may be one of the PC cleaner was doing this. So I uninstalled them(may be **glary utility** was the problem) and it seems to be ok now. I can run my PC fine now.

On this troubleshooting time I also found out the possible causes and solutions about this **blue screen** problem. *Those are:*

1. It may be for a faulty hardware or connecting error of them.
2. It may be caused by a driver.
3. It may happen for windows file corruption. *etc*

So may be the right approach would be to find the cause in **Event Viewer** and find a solution for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to point to the correct cause of this, as there is very few technical information about the BSOD details.

From your description, my gut feelings and the different STOP messages, I would exchange the memory. Defect RAM modules do have a long history of beeing responsible for "random" STOP codes and super weird systen behaviour.

Comment: Can it be a problem caused by Hard disk or OS?

Comment: Shure, it **can**.